# orcaledb for nodejs with impersonation

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

Actually am looking for a technical explanation for the thing that I am doing. am not an expert for orcaldb for nodejs.
I have a nodejs application used as API with Expressjs, connecting with the database is done with orcaledb single connection, BUT I am using user impersonation to make the connection to be able to take the user privileges in Oracle.

```
 oracledb.getConnection({
        user: dbConfig.user + ((user_Id === '') ? '' : '[' + user_Id + ']'),
        password: dbConfig.password,
        connectString: dbConfig.connectString
    }
```

what am asking is;
Using the connection in this way do behave as Pool connection sense the user is changed every time, or its single connection. the main-user have got grant access for sub-user. main-user[sub-user].
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BUT I am using user impersonation to make the connection to be able to take the user privileges in Oracle

The term for the feature you're using is "proxy authentication".

> Using the connection in this way do behave as Pool connection sense the user is changed every time, or its single connection.

It's still a single connection. The two features are distinct: connection pool and proxy authentication. You can use either one independently or both together.

The idea behind the pool is to reduce the overhead associated with creating new connections (new process, memory allocation, etc.). Since you're working with an Express web server, chances are you're creating a multi-user application. That's the type of application that would benefit from a connection pool (as opposed to a job that runs every hour, for example).

There are several uses for proxy authentication, but one of the primary uses is identity preservation. In other words, rather than connect as a single generic user, you can proxy connect as the end user. This allows for better integration with security features such as roles and auditing.

To combine both, see the section of the doc on [Pool Proxy Authentication](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#pool-proxy-authentication).